# Add GeoJSON as Marker on a Map

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-marker

My goal is very simple, but I struggle to implement it. I tried different ways, many examples and tuts but anything every time failed.

What I need: A Simple map with markers I deliver via GeoJSON file.

What I have been trying:

- Import the GeoJSON to Mapbox as Tileset (Cant set a Custom-Icon, so it looks ugly with just dots)
- Load GeoJSON local and each to display as marker (doesnt work)

```js
        var showInfoDialog = false;
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicnNiYXVtYW5uIiwiYSI6IjdiOWEzZGIyMGNkOGY3NWQ4ZTBhN2Y5ZGU2Mzg2NDY2In0.jycgv7qwF8MMIWt4cT0RaQ';
  var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
   container: 'map',
   style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9',
   center: [-74.0059, 40.7128],
   zoom: 15.5,
            pitch: 45,
            minZoom: 9,
            maxZoom: 18,
   bearing: -25.0,
           
  });
        
            
        
        map.once('style.load', function(e) {
            
            // Insert the layer beneath any symbol layer.
            var layers = map.getStyle().layers;

            var labelLayerId;
            for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
                if (layers[i].type === 'symbol' && layers[i].layout['text-field']) {
                    labelLayerId = layers[i].id;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            map.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
                positionOptions: {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true
                },
                trackUserLocation: true
            }));            

            if (window.location.search.indexOf('embed') !== -1) map.scrollZoom.disable();
            
            map.addSource('geojson', {
                type: 'geojson',
                data: 'https:/xxxxx.json'
            });
              /*
             // add markers to map
            map.getSource('geojson').forEach(function(marker) {
                // create a DOM element for the marker
                var el = document.createElement('div');
                el.className = 'marker';
                el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://map.gogames.live/images/arena.png';
                el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
                el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';

                el.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    window.alert(marker.properties.name);
                });

                // add marker to map
                new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
                    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
                    .addTo(map);
            });
            */
            
            
            //Hide loading bar once tiles from geojson are loaded
            map.on('data', function(e) {
                if (e.dataType === 'source' && e.sourceId === 'arenen') {
                    document.getElementById("loader").style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.map-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.map-overlay .map-overlay-inner {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.map-overlay-inner fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
/* Dark attribution */

.mapboxgl-ctrl.mapboxgl-ctrl-attrib {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

.mapboxgl-ctrl.mapboxgl-ctrl-attrib a {
  color: #fff;
}
/* Dark popup */

.mapboxgl-popup-content {
  background-color: #202020;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-anchor-bottom-left .mapboxgl-popup-tip,
.mapboxgl-popup-anchor-bottom-right .mapboxgl-popup-tip,
.mapboxgl-popup-anchor-bottom .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
  border-top-color: #202020;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top-left .mapboxgl-popup-tip,
.mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top-right .mapboxgl-popup-tip,
.mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
  border-bottom-color: #202020;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-anchor-right .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
  border-left-color: #202020;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-anchor-left .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
  border-right-color: #202020;
}

#popup-menu ul,
#menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.mapboxgl-ctrl-group {
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
}

.loader {
  margin: -10px 0 0 -250px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  z-index: 9999;
}
/*
Set the color of the icon
*/

svg path,
svg rect {
    fill: #FF6700;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.49.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.49.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v2.3.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v2.3.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css' type='text/css' />
<link href='https://www.mapbox.com/base/latest/base.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="map"></div>
    <div class='map-overlay top'>
        <div class='map-overlay-inner'>
            <fieldset>
                <label><b>Special Map</b></label>
                
            </fieldset>
            <b><a href="x" target="_blank">Some Info</a></b>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div class="loader loader--style1" title="0" id="loader">
        <svg version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 40 40" enable-background="new 0 0 40 40" xml:space="preserve">
            <path opacity="0.2" fill="#000" d="M20.201,5.169c-8.254,0-14.946,6.692-14.946,14.946c0,8.255,6.692,14.946,14.946,14.946
    s14.946-6.691,14.946-14.946C35.146,11.861,28.455,5.169,20.201,5.169z M20.201,31.749c-6.425,0-11.634-5.208-11.634-11.634
    c0-6.425,5.209-11.634,11.634-11.634c6.425,0,11.633,5.209,11.633,11.634C31.834,26.541,26.626,31.749,20.201,31.749z" />
            <path fill="#000" d="M26.013,10.047l1.654-2.866c-2.198-1.272-4.743-2.012-7.466-2.012h0v3.312h0
    C22.32,8.481,24.301,9.057,26.013,10.047z">
                <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 20 20" to="360 20 20" dur="0.5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </path>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

So maybe some one can explain me whats the best practise to realize this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have added the source, but need to add a layer to the map as well. You can do both in one step with `map.addLayer` (see Mapbox's [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-markers/)).

Comment: This example shows custom markers, not just simple regular markers... which appears to be impossible given how long I've been searching to no avail.

Comment: The default marker is supported only when creating the marker programmatically. Styling should specify what image to use. That, imho, is inconsistent behaviour, there should be sensible defaults if one is fine with predefined marker icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to download geojson and show it on the map view.

```
guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
do {
       let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
       let shape = try MGLShape(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
       let shapeClass = shape.classForCoder

       if shapeClass == MGLPointFeature.self {
            if let pointFeature = shape as? MGLPointFeature {
                pointFeature.title = pointFeature.attributes["title"] as? String

                let shapeSource = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "PointShapeSource", shape: pointFeature, options: nil)

                let circleStyleLayer = MGLCircleStyleLayer(identifier: "PointCircleStyleLayer", source: shapeSource)
                circleStyleLayer.circleColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.orange)
                circleStyleLayer.circleStrokeWidth = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 24.0)
                circleStyleLayer.circleStrokeColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor(red:1, green:0.76, blue:0.63, alpha:1.0))

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                     [unowned self] in
                     self.mapView.setCenter(pointFeature.coordinate, animated: true)
                     self.mapView.style?.addSource(shapeSource)
                     self.mapView.style?.addLayer(circleStyleLayer)
                 })
           }
        }
} catch let error {
}
```